# Next.js inline script only loads once

Tags: javascript, next.js

I've implemented [Tiny Slider](http://ganlanyuan.github.io/tiny-slider/demo/) in my Next.js app which requires an inline script on the page to control the slider's behavior. Now while the script loads properly the first time I launch index.js, however whenever I navigate to another page using Link and come back to index.js, the script doesn't load.

Here's how I've written the script in index.js

```
 {/* Script */}
        <Script id='tester'>
          {`
            var slider = tns({
              container: '.my-slider',
              items: 6,
              autoplay: true,
              autoplayTimeout: 2000,
              gutter: 20,
              autoplayButtonOutput: false,
              controls: false,
              navPosition: 'bottom',
              nav: false,
              mouseDrag: true,
              arrowKeys: true,
              responsive: {
                300: {
                  items: 2,
                  gutter: 50,
                  center: true,
                  fixedWidth: 250,
                },
                700: {
                  items: 3,
                  gutter: 50,
                  center: true,
                  fixedWidth: 250,
                },
                1440: {
                  items: 3,
                  gutter: 50,
                  fixedWidth: 250,
                  center: true,
                }
              }
            });
          `}
        </Script>
```

I need the script to load every time index.js loads, not just the first time around. Any ideas on how I can do this? The entire code is here - https://github.com/YaddyVirus/Esttheva

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps to adding tiny-slider to a next.js app.

1. Add a pages/_document.js to load the styles

```js
// pages/_document.js
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/tiny-slider.css" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

2. Here is an example page that loads the slider

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    let slider;
    // Tiny slider only can be loaded once and can only be loaded clint side
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && ref.current) {
      ref.current = false;
      // Lazy load the slider code client side
      import("tiny-slider").then((x) => {
        slider = x.tns({
          container: ".slider",
          items: 3,
          slideBy: "page",
          autoplay: true
        });
      });
    }
    // Destory the slider when it is unmouted
    return slider?.destroy();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="slider">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Link to code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tina-slider-nextjs-0z8zi6?file=/pages/index.js:0-806

Here is a couple of key notes about the solution

- The `ref` keeps track of if the hook as already been called (as of react 18 hooks get called twice in dev mode)
- We use `typeof window !== "undefined"` to ensure that tiny-window only gets loaded client side and **not** on the server (this causes a "window is undefined" Error)
- We are calling the `tns` function [as per the docs](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider#3-call-tns)